# Solution of a particular Backward SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have been reading about backward SDEs and their existence-uniqueness result. The results are available for equations of the form $$ -dY_t = f(t,\omega, Y_t,Z_t)\,dt- Z_t\,dW_t, \quad Y_T= \xi.$$
A solution is a pair $(Y_t,Z_t)$ such that $Z_t$ is predictable and we must have the relation $Y_t= \xi + \int^T_t f\,ds-\int^T_tZ_s\,dW_s$. So my question is if we have a SDE of the form $-dY_t = f(Y_t)\,dt- cdW_t,\,\, Y_T= \xi$, i.e. the diffusion coefficient is constant, can we still talk about existence and uniqueness? Will $(Y_t, c)$ be a pair of solution or will there be some issue?

Comment: Typo in your constant-diffusion SDE?

Comment: Yes, thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for simplicity that $f=0$. With $Z_{s}=c$ we get
\begin{equation*}
Y_{t}=\xi-\int_{t}^{T} Z_{s}dW_{s}=\xi-c\left(W_{T}-W_{t}\right).
\end{equation*}
Unless $\xi$ looks something like $a +cW_{T}$ so that terms cancel, we end up with a $Y_{t}$ depending on the increment $W_{T}-W_{t}$. You haven't actually written anything (like the word "adapted") to exclude that possibility, but probably you wanted to?

Comment: If we do not know the exact solution, at least can we say the existence of solution? What I am looking for is the existing theory applicable?

Comment: A requirement is for $Y$ to be adapted, if $\xi$ is not "compensating" for the $cW_T$ term then it is not ok

Comment: Okay, I understood the point. The term $\xi$ will have to be random as well, it cannot be an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Noone is suggesting that $\xi$ should be constant. That would not help you anyway unless $c=0$. You should infer from what I wrote that a solution can exist only when $\xi$ has a form like $a+cW_{T}$ (still very much a random variable).

Comment: Thank you Ali I understood.